# How to work with images in pure Django templates so that they work like they do in Wagtail

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I intend to use images in my Django blog app, and I am wondering how do I go about this.

So I only want one image to be uploaded with each post page. I added an `ImageField()` so that's that, however I can't force images to be uploaded to media/ folder. Also, I don't know how to force images to be automatically resized and have their names automatically changed.

Right now, the declaration for the field handling Images is really simple

```
main_image = ImageField(upload_to='media/', null=True)
```

I don't really know how to do any of this, even though I have done my fair share of googling

Answer (score 0):

For cropping images you can use `PIL` https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

And for renaming the image you can define a method and call that method in the upload_to field as:

```
ImageField(..., upload_to=method_call(params),....)
```

The function can be defined as:

```
def some_name(instance, filename, path):
    path = path
    filename = "..."
    return os.path.join(path, filename)
```